# In activeJDBC, how to enforce the presence of a one-to-many relationship to a model

Tags: java, activejdbc

Assuming I have the following DB model:

```
Car(
  id             INT
  plaque_id      INT

)

Plaque(
  id             INT
  identification TEXT
)
```

So in ActiveJDBC, my models are:

```
public class Car extends Model {

    static{
        validatePresenceOf("plaque_id");
    }

    public Car () {}
}
```

..

```
public class Plaque extends Model {

        static{
            validatePresenceOf("identification");
        }

        public Car () {}
    }
```

Assuming my specification says: a car must have a plaque.

As you can see, I am enforcing the presence of plaque_id to the Car model.

Now. When I try this:

```
Car model_s = new Car();
Plaque plaque_a = new Plaque();

plaque_a.set("identification","A-8000");
plaque_a.saveIt();

car.add(plaque_a);
car.saveIt();
```

I got the following exception thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can only add associated model
>   to an instance that exists in DB. Save this instance first, then you
>   will be able to add dependencies to it.

If I understand correctly, my car *model_s* must be saved first before being able to link plaque *plaque_a*. But I cannot save *model_s* without a plaque due to my validation rule. It's a catch-22.

Note: I am new to activeJDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got it backwards. Since your table `Car` has a column `plaque_id`, it means that a `Plaque` has many `Car`(s), which is a One-to-Many association: http://javalite.io/one_to_many_associations.

Therefore, you need to add `Car` to `Plaque`, and not the other way around:

```
Car model_s = new Car();    // set parameters on the car
plaque_a.set("identification","A-8000");
plaque_a.saveIt();
plaque_a.add(model_s);
```

Other recommendations:

1) In Java, use CamelCase: `modelS`, not `model_s`

2) Add constructor to `Plaque`:

```
public class Plaque{
   public Plaque(String identification){ 
      set("identification", identification);
   }
   public Plaque(){} // must have default constructor
}
```

then your code will look cleaner:

```
Car model_s = new Car();    // set parameters on the car
Plaque plaque = new Plaque("A-8000");
plaque_a.saveIt();
plaque_a.add(modelS);
```

Generally, try to avoid dynamic setters and getters, they are OK for a small project, but [writing permanent setters and getters](http://javalite.io/setters_and_getters#wrapper-settersgetters) will get you an amazing power of Java refactoring, something you do not have in Ruby.